# BioPython produces inconsistent BLOSUM matrices

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am working with BLOSUM matrix values and I use [`Bio`](https://biopython.org/) Python package.

```py
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo

MatrixInfo.blosum80['Y', 'D']
# outputs -4
```

The answer seems correct but I also get a warning indicating that this package is deprecated.

```
C:\Users\ibrah\anaconda3\envs\MyVenvBioinformatics\lib\site-packages\Bio\SubsMat\__init__.py:126: BiopythonDeprecationWarning: Bio.SubsMat has been deprecated, and we intend to remove it in a future release of Biopython. As an alternative, please consider using Bio.Align.substitution_matrices as a replacement, and contact the Biopython developers if you still need the Bio.SubsMat module.
  warnings.warn(
```

So, I tried to use `substitution_matrices` (as suggested in warning above).

```py
from Bio.Align import substitution_matrices

BLOSUM80 = substitution_matrices.load('BLOSUM80')
BLOSUM80['Y', 'D']
# -6
```

This, however, produces different result from the previous one. I have searched it online and correct answer should be `-4` according to [this web page](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Esoni/cs21/s12/Labs/images/07/blosum80.php).

For now, I am manually parsing the BLOSUM txt file. I am confused why they produce different matrices and can I achieve the same matrix using `Bio.Align.substitution_matrices`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: BLOSUM80 values differ - but what's the reason?[https://www.biostars.org/p/190004/]